# Extracting my Telegram channel list?

Tags: telegram

Is there a way to extract a list of my currently enrolled/joined telegram channels at once ?

Comment: It really depends on whether they're public or private, and the information you want to export - could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

**Telegram now supports data export as part of the GDPR changes**, you can [read my more detailed answer on another question on the site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118186/177684).

Specifically about your question, a demonstration from Telegram Desktop, for exporting you channels (and so you'll get to list them all, and can ignore the messages):

[image]